# Android studio 3.5 requires Refresh Linked C++ project each time I build the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Since I updated to Android Studio 3.5 when ever I run the application (no matter which button I pick) first thing that happens is this error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /.cxx/cmake/prodDebug/arm64-v8a --target jni-lib}
[1/5] Building CXX object ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/LocationExpert.cpp.o
[2/5] Building CXX object ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/ElasticGPS.cpp.o
[3/5] Building CXX object ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/GRRunnableHandler.cpp.o
[4/5] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/prodDebug/obj/arm64-v8a/libMobileNativeCoreSharedLib.so
FAILED: : && /android-ndk-r16/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/android-ndk-r16/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /android-ndk-r16/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot /android-ndk-r16/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libMobileNativeCoreSharedLib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/prodDebug/obj/arm64-v8a/libMobileNativeCoreSharedLib.so ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/LocationExpert.cpp.o ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/ElasticGPS.cpp.o ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/GRRunnableHandler.cpp.o ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/DistanceCalculator.cpp.o ../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/Logger.cpp.o  -llog -latomic -lm "/android-ndk-r16/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
../../../../mobileCore/CMakeFiles/MobileNativeCoreSharedLib.dir/DistanceCalculator.cpp.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

*--- Some folder names/user names were omitted ---*

Only after I "Refresh linked C++ projects" / "Clean project", the application will then compile, build and install on the device.

This started happening only after upgrading AS to 3.5.

Any clues why? 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your CMakeLists.txt and build.gradle? There's not really enough to go on here.

Comment: You should probably upgrade your NDK. The new Gradle Plugin may be not prepared to work smoothly with NDK r16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I gathered that building for arm64-v8a during debug has stopped functioning correctly for some reason in AS 3.5.

So as a fix for release builds, I simply use

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64
}
```

and

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64
    }
```

for debug builds heh.

Perhaps, some day, I'll look into the exact reason why 'arm64-v8a' fails. 
Anyway, this solved the problem for me :)

Comment: where I can add your Script inside '  externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
          
        } '

Comment: @engmms I'm adding these inside the buildType {} section. release build type gets the first one and the debug build type gets the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open your old project with Android Studio 3.5? As I know, Android studio 3.5 have a new diffrent native project structure. It place both the source code and CMakeLists under the "app/src/main/cpp" folder,the old version studio place CMakeLists under "app/" and source code under "app/src/main/jni". You can try to create a empty native project with Android Studio 3.5, and place your code same way as this empty native project does.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, I tried your suggestion. Moved everything to /main/cpp, the same way the sample project is doing, I still get the same error.